# Opening Links in a PDF in a New Tab

Tags: java, pdf, hyperlink

I hope this is the right place to post this - my manager said the solution to this problem was "something to do with coding" and as I'm pretty much a novice in that field I hope someone here can help or at least point me in the right direction.

I'm having an issue getting hyperlinks in PDFs to open documents in a new tab. I'll try to explain the situation the best I can, but apologies in advance if this isn't a great explanation:

I have one PDF document ("doc A") with links to other documents (for example, doc B), all of which are saved on the company intranet. Each of these documents has links to multiple other documents (eg, doc C), also saved on the intranet.

When I click on the link in doc A, it takes me to doc B. It opens the "document information" page in one tab and doc B in a second tab. So far, so good.

When I click on the link in doc B, it displays doc C. It opens doc C in a new tab, but opens the document information page in the same tab that was previously displaying doc B.

Basically, how can I force the hyperlink to open the page in a new tab? My manager assures me it is possible to do this without editing the hyperlink in the uploaded documents... how do I do this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO ! 
Do you already have some code to share ? What language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you are searching for,

```html
<a href="xyz.org" target="_blank">MyWebSite</a>
```

**target="_blank"** helps you open the page which is given within anchor tab in a new tab.